# Integral of $(\ln(x)/x)^n$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, gamma-function

How would you go about integrating the function $\left(\frac{\ln(x)}{x}\right)^n$ for some integer $n≥2$?

I've managed to recursively calculate it using integration by parts to get a nasty series but WolframAlpha says it's equal to $$\frac{-\Gamma(n+1,(n-1)\ln(x))}{(n-1)^{n+1}}$$

where $\Gamma(a,x)$ is the incomplete gamma function.
Why is this the case?

Comment: Try the substitution $x=\mathrm{e}^{t/(n-1)}$ and use the definition of the incomplete gamma function.

Answer (score 1):

Since Lai give an nice answer for your question using the Gamma incomplete function. I will try avoid (in some sense) the special function. Now, we can start slightly different using the substitution $t:=1/x$, then $dt=-1/x^2 dx$ and we have for $n\in {\bf N}$, $$\int \frac{\ln^{n}(x)}{x^{n}}dx=\int \frac{\ln^{n}\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)}{\frac{1}{t^{n}}}\left(\frac{-1}{t^{2}}\right)dt=(-1)^{n+1}\int t^{n-2}\ln^{n}(t) dt$$
The last primitive is part of article in Wikipedia about the [Sophomore dream](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream#Historical_proof) and as indicated in the article can be find using integration by parts and using the falling factorial notation $(n)_{k}$, that is, for $(m,n)\in {\bf N}\times {\bf N}$

$$\int t^{m}\ln^{n}(t)dt=\frac{t^{m+1}}{m+1}\sum_{0\leqslant k\leqslant n}(-1)^{k}\frac{(n)_{k}}{(m+1)^{k}}\ln^{n-k}(t).$$

Then, the result it is follows, setting $m:=n-2$.

*Note:* We can show that the falling factorial it is related with the Gamma function, since $(t)_{k}=\frac{\Gamma(t+1)}{\Gamma(t-k+1)}$.

Answer (score 0):

As Gary suggested, let $x=e^{\frac{t}{n-1} }$, then $t=(n-1)\ln x$ and $$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int \frac{\left(\frac{t}{n-1}\right)^n}{e^{\frac{n t}{n-1}}} \cdot \frac{1}{n-1} e^{\frac{t}{n-1}} d t \\
& =\frac{1}{(n-1)^{n+1}} \int t^n e^{-t} d t \\
& =-\frac{1}{(n-1)^{n+1}} \Gamma(n+1, t)\\&=-\frac{1}{(n-1)^{n+1}} \Gamma(n+1,(n-1)\ln x)
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: $\int {t^n {\rm e}^{ - t} {\rm d}t}  =  \color{red}{-} \Gamma (n + 1,t)$